# Different standard Aqua space in ios 7 and 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I'm using Xcode 7 beta 4, Mac OSX 10.10. My app's deployment target is iOS 7.0.

I know that standard Aqua space is 20 between a view and its superview. But when I design storyboard for iOS 7, I must use 8, like this:

[image]

[image: It looks fine]

and it looks fine (above constraints is for search bar). When I run iOS 8 simulator, it appears like this:

[image]

So I must use right value is 20. But using 20 will cut off subview in iOS 7.

Anyone know if this is a bug or is there anything different between iOS 7 and 8? This happens with all simulators and real devices too.

Comment: What I want is to fill subview on screen, so I must use -20 for trailing and leading space. But I mean, whatever value you give, it will be different between iOS 7 and 8, and I don't know why.

Comment: My app must support iOS 7 :) If I changed it to 8.0 then there will be no problem, everything is fine with iOS 8.

Comment: yes...thats the problem...because it supports only 7.0 and lower when you test it in 8.0...it takes nothing for 8.0

Comment: I don't think it's only 7.0 and lower. I think it is only 7.0 and _higher_?

Comment: your deployment taget is 7.0 then it supports 7.0 and lower and if its 8.0 then 8.0 and lower...so it supports 7.0 too...it doen't mean higher from deployment target